# Redux state - Add/Edit/Remove object and its properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, lodash

This is the reducer state. I need to add, update, remove the object in cartData. At the first time, cartData is empty.

```
const initialState = {
   fetchData: {},
   cartData: {}
}
```

**Example:**

```
fetchData: {
  "React":{'name': 'React'},
  "Node":{'name': 'Node'},
}
```

If user `ADD_ITEM` react book, new item is adding in the cart here.

```
cartData:{
  "React":{'name': 'React', 'quantity': 1}, 
}
```

If user `Edit_ITEM` react book, existing item is updating here.

```
cartData:{
  "React":{'name': 'React', 'quantity': 4}, 
}
```

If user `REMOVE_ITEM` react book, removing when its come to zero here.

```
cartData:{

}
```

How can we modify redux state for these actions?

**Tried this:** using `lodash`. But did't worked out correctly.

```
case types.ADD_ITEM:
   return { ...state, cartData: // add new item  }

case types.EDIT_ITEM:
   return { ...state, [state.cartData.name]: action.payload  }

case types.REMOVE_ITEM:
   return _.omit(state, [state.cartData.name]: action.payload)
```

Comment: Are you looking for reducers and action dispatchers?

Comment: looking for reducers to update the state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use spread syntax for `add` and `edit` items and `Object.keys()` and `reduce()` for remove item.

```js
const initialState = {
 fetchData: {},
 cartData: {}
}

function cartReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'ADD_ITEM':
    return {...state, cartData: {...state.cartData, ...action.payload}}
    
    case 'EDIT_ITEM':
    return {...state, cartData: {...state.cartData, ...action.payload}}
    
    case 'REMOVE_ITEM':
    let newState = Object.keys(state.cartData).reduce((r, e) => {
      if(!action.payload[e]) r[e] = state.cartData[e];
      return r
    }, {})
    
    return {...state, cartData: newState}
    
    default:
    return state;
  }
}

var state = {}

state = cartReducer(undefined, {
  type: 'ADD_ITEM',
  payload: {"React":{'name': 'React', 'quantity': 1}}
})
console.log(state)

state = cartReducer(state, {
  type: 'ADD_ITEM',
  payload: {"Node":{'name': 'Node', 'quantity': 2}}
})
console.log(state)

state =  cartReducer(state, {
  type: 'EDIT_ITEM',
  payload: {"React":{'name': 'React', 'quantity': 4}}
})
console.log(state)

state = cartReducer(state, {
  type: 'REMOVE_ITEM',
  payload: {"React":{'name': 'React', 'quantity': 1}}
})
console.log(state)
```

Answer (score 1):

In actions:

```
const editData = (items) => (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({type: 'EDIT_ITEMS', payload: items});
}
```

In reducer:

```
const reducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action){
    case 'EDIT_ITEMS': {
         if(_.isEmpty(action.payload)){
                 return {
                         ...state,
                         cartData: {},
                 };
         } else {
                 return {
                         ...state,
                         cellData: action.payload,
                 };
         }
    }
}
```

This should be the way to do it. `payload` should be all the items you've in the cart at any point of time.

**[EDIT:]** 
As the question has been edited, You can also do that using `deleting` a key, using

```
// Ref: https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/issues/962#issuecomment-219354496
export const removeByKey = (object, deleteKey) => {
  return Object.keys(object)
    .filter(key => key !== deleteKey)
    .reduce((result, current) => {
      result[current] = object[current];
      return result;
    }, {});
};

case types.REMOVE_ITEM:
   return { ...state, cartData: deleteKey(cartData, action.payload)) }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know exactly what you are trying. Below is an example of a reducer function with an add to cart method. You'll need to add a similar method for each of your scenarios.

```
export function reducer(state = initialState, action: any): State {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "ADD_TO_CART": {
            return {
                fetchData: state.fetchData,
                cartData: Object.assign({}, state.cartData, action.payload}
            };
        }
    }
    default: {
        return state;
    }
}
```

You will then dispatch the action by calling the dispatch function:

```
dispatch({
    type: "ADD_TO_CART",
    payload: "React":{'name': 'React', 'quantity': 1}
})
```